# Volume reaching over top arrays

Tags: java, arrays

> Given an array of positive integers representing terrain heights (in 2-d, ala Super Mario)) and an integer representing a flat sea level, return a container of integers representing the volume of each unique body of water.

**Please do not solve the whole problem for me!**

I have a few questions:

Lets take an example first.

```
int [] arr = {4, 3, 5, 6, 4, 2};

int sea_level = 4;
```

The way it is set up is like this:

```
      6
    5 6
4   5 6 4 2
4 3 5 6 4 2
4 3 5 6 4 2
4 3 5 6 4 2
```

**Q** So we can't cross over 4 right?

So we have the ranges, [4, 3] and [4, 2] (after the [5, 6] range).

But how do I calculate the volume?

```
Arraylist<Integer> list = new Arraylist<>();
int volume = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    if(arr[i] <= sea_level){
        volume += arr[i];
    } else{
        list.add(volume); //volume for one block, then reset down.
        volume = 0; //loop starts with the next one.
    }
}
```

Is this the way to go about it? I don't understand the problem.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: I think you're close, except that the value that you're adding to `volume` is wrong.  Look at the case where `arr[i]` is 3.  If the terrain is 3 units high, I think that means the land that's under water is 3 units high.  So if sea level is 4 units, then how much room is there for water?  At least that's how I understand the problem.

Comment: 4 - 3? How did you calculate it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your example:

```
       6
     5 6     5
 4   5 6     5
 4 3 5 6     5 
 4 3 5 6 2   5
 4 3 5 6 2 1 5
```

The water line is at 4, so:

```
       6
     5 6     5
 ~~~~~~~~~~~~5
 4   5 6     5
 4 3 5 6     5
 4 3 5 6 2   5
 4 3 5 6 2 1 5
```

Which makes the water *volume* the holes beneath the water line, or:

```
       6
     5 6     5
 ~~~~~~~~~~~~5
 4 W 5 6 W W 5
 4 3 5 6 W W 5
 4 3 5 6 2 W 5
 4 3 5 6 2 1 5
```

or, 1 cube of water, and then 5 cubes of water.

Now, how do you calculate that... you need the volume.
The volume is measured between the waterline (4) and the terrain height...
So to measure the volume: sea_level - a[i]